# mysqli can't connect as a non-root user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm designing a test page with XAMPP that uses a verification method to login. Until now, I've been using the 'root' account in order to check if the user that is trying to login actually exists (if I try to connect as the login user, and it doesn't exist or password doesn't match, it instantly throws fatal error), but this of course makes the root account vulnerable as the password is shown on the code. So I thought about creating a new user, with only **SELECT** privileges, and use it to check for the login user. However, whenever I try to run the code, it throws fatal error too.

Code that gives the error:
`$conn = new mysqli('localhost', "test_conn", "1234", "mysql");`

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'test_conn'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\[path]\sesion.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\[path]\sesion.php(41): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'test_conn', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'mysql') #1 {main} thrown in C:\[path]\sesion.php on line 41
```

User select on phpMyAdmin (shortened, rest of the values are "N" or empty):

```
 Host   User    Password    Select_priv
%   test_conn   *A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF   Y
localhost   test_conn       Y
```

Tried possible solutions:

- Replacing 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1'
- Altering 'host' column to 'localhost' (the user I made had '%' as host, as seen on the select statement)
- Replacing 'localhost' with '%'

Comment: It seems my problem got solved by just setting up the password for the 'localhost' host one. I noticed that after posting this question and checking the SELECT statement. Regardless, I'll keep this question open because I'm curious about how could I connect the '%' user account instead of the 'localhost' one, as the '%' part gave me fatal error on the page despite having both user and password setted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database named `mysql` is a reserved one and only accessible using user `root`.

I think you can give certain permission to your user. But using root will be wiser!

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test_conn'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### Or you're using db name by mistake!

You have to create a database and use its name in php code!

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', "my_user", "1234", "my_db_name");
```

And for mysql part:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_db_name; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db_name.* TO 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This code creates a database called `my_db_name`, then creates a user named `my_user` using password `1234` and gives that user all permissions on the created database!

Comment: Doesn't this give 'admin' perms to the test user? What I was going for is to have an user that can check (and only do that) tables to verify that the login is correct, since both the password and username would be shown on the code part. Unless there's something I'm missing in this.

Comment: Your database name in code is `mysql`. `mysql` is the name of a reserved database! you should fix your database name and give your user access to that database!

Comment: @Koori Added some more info. if it was helpful accept and vote up, please.

Comment: I'm either not following or this isn't what I aim for. I want my test user to be able to SELECT on my initial DB (mysql) since there's where I store the users and its passwords. So after the `$conn` part is executed, I have a line of code that SELECTS to find if both the user and pass exists and matches (```$veri = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $pass . "';");```, both user and pass variables comes from a form). Creating another DB shouldn't let my test user check for the table content that's being stored in my initial DB, right?

Comment: @Koori in the first line `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', "test_conn", "1234", "mysql");` you are connecting to a database called `mysql`! it is a database reserved for mysql it self! you should save your logins in a different database!

Comment: @Koori In my example I used `my_db_name`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't getting your point. I'll make another DB for storing users, thanks! It's my first time using XAMPP and I thought I could make use of `mysql` DB for my web page.